# Is it possible to embed the .ttf font file completely in the webpage so there's no need to request the file when loading my page?

Tags: html, fonts, frontend, font-face

Sometimes my page loads not so smoothly because it waits for the `.ttf` file to be loaded.

Is there any way I can embed it inline?

Just like to turn `<img src="xxxx">` into `<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64, ...`.

Comment: Very interesting sir. Never thought on this line. This opens the box for including all files as needed at Client end. Will await inputs of experts here. Bookmarked your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in exactly the same fashion.

```
<style>
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'myfont';
    src: url('data:font/ttf;base64,...') format('truetype');
  }
  .myfont {
    font-family: 'myfont';
  }
</style>
```

A data URL is a kind of URL. As far as I am aware, in HTML/CSS, anywhere you can use a URL, you can use a data URL; just make sure to assign it the proper MIME type (and text encoding, if necessary).

However, this should rarely be needed. If your page frequently waits for a file to load, you might want to check your cache headers, and configure your web server to match your expectations; ideally, the browser should load your file only once, then remember it for a good long time.